# Eclipse starts freezing after pressing backslash

Tags: php, eclipse, backslash

I have a problem with PHP for Eclipse. It starts freezing or working very very hard after I use "/" character. What can cause the problem?

Comment: Have you heard about our lord and savior [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)?

Comment: What is you PDT and Eclipse version? Best way to investigate/fix will be PDT bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT  use this article to prepare ticket: https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock